# autotable not found in jsPDF

Tags: jspdf-autotable

i have the same problem since.
1. installed jsPDF and jspdf-autotable with
   npm install jspdf
   npm install --save @types/jspdf
   npm install jspdf-autotable --save

2. Import jspdf into app.component.ts with
     import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
     import 'jspdf-autotable';
3. this is my method.ts

```js
generatedile(){
          var columns = [
            {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
            {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
            {title: "Country", dataKey: "country"},
        ];
        var rows = [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Shaw", "country": "Tanzania"},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Nelson", "country": "Kazakhstan"},
            {"id": 3, "name": "Garcia", "country": "Madagascar"},
        ];
         
        // Only pt supported (not mm or in)
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
            styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
            columnStyles: {
              id: {fillColor: 255}
            },
            margin: {top: 60},
            addPageContent: function(data) {
              doc.text("Header", 40, 30);
            }
        });
        doc.save('table.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not import jspdf-autotable. Try this

```
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
require('jspdf-autotable');
```